# How can I create this shape.xml programmatically/dynamically in Android. Set stroke color(pics/code included)

Tags: android

I need to create this shape programmatically (I need to change its stroke color depending on what a user chooses)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   android:shape="oval" >
<solid
    android:color="#FFEECC"
    />
<size
    android:width="100dp"
android:height="100dp"
/>

<stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#444444" />


</shape>
```

I tried using ShapeDrawable but it doesn't appear to have a stroke color option?  Also, shapes will tend to stretch no matter what width or height you set for them? can anyone explain this?

tried this

```
ShapeDrawable sd = new ShapeDrawable();
            sd.setShape(new OvalShape());
            sd.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(20);
            sd.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason, you need to use a `GradientDrawable` (forcing a solid color instead of a real gradient):

```
    int backgroundColor = Color.RED;
    int strokeColor = Color.GRAY;
    int strokeSize = 10;
    GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[]{backgroundColor, backgroundColor});
    drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
    drawable.setStroke(strokeSize, strokeColor);
    //...use your drawable
```

This is what you get using the above code:

[image]

In order to achieve the **shadow effect**, use the *elevation* attribute or create a [LayerListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html) with a shadow layer.